# is there any other way to read data from file?

Tags: c, file

[image: photo of file]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  FILE *fp;
  int a[25], i = 0, o[25], e[25];
  fp = fopen("number.txt", "r");

  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &a[i]);
    if (a[i] < 2 && a[i] > -2) {
      if (a[i] == 0)
        e[i] = a[i];
      else
        o[i] = a[i];
    } else if (a[i] % 2 == 0)
      e[i] = a[i];
    else
      o[i] = a[i];
  }
  fclose(fp);
  fp = fopen("even.txt", "w+");
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    fprintf(fp, "%d ", e[i]);
  }
  fclose(fp);
  fp = fopen("odd.txt", "w+");
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    fprintf(fp, "%d ", o[i]);
  }
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

here i am trying to read numbers from file named number and then differentiating them as odd and even. after that I am copying odd to a file named odd and even to a file named even but instead of copying the correct numbers, its copying random values[image]

Comment: Do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger and examine it as it runs. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). One problem: `if(a[i]==0) e[i]=a[i]; else o[i]=a[i];` that results in "holes" in the arrays. Which is exactly what the resulting files show. In each iteration, `i` is incremented but only one of the arrays will have a value set at that `i` index.

Answer (score 1):

Do this as the first step:

```c
for (i = 0; i < 25; ++i) e[i] = o[i] = 9999;
```

Then you'll hopefully figure out that there are `9999` values interspersed in both final arrays.

As to why, consider the sequence `7, 8`. The seven goes into `a[0]` and then, being odd, also to `o[0]`.

The eight goes into `a[1]` and then, being even, also to `e[1]`, leaving `e[0]` holding whatever arbitrary value it had before this step. That's because you use `i` for all three array accesses:

```
index:   0  1  2  3 ...
-----------------------
e:       ?  8  ?  ? ...
o:       7  ?  ?  ? ...
```

What you would be better off doing is maintaining three *separate* counts. In fact, *two* would be fine because you never need to use the input number again after it's sent to the correct array. That means `a[]` in unnecessary.

For example (and take particular notice of the longer variable names, this will become invaluable when you later look at the code, or someone else has to):

```c
int value, oddIdx = 0, evenIdx = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
    if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &value) != 1) // should handle invalid data.
        ;
    if (value % 2 == 0) {
        evens[evenIdx++] = value;
    } else {
        odds[oddIdx++] = value;
    }
```

Also take note of the simplified odd/even check in that code. I'm not sure *why* you thought you had to treat `-1, 0, 1` as a special case in your original code but they work just fine.

Then to print them (standard output here but files in your case):

```c
for (int i = 0; i < oddIdx; ++i)
    printf("Odd : %d\n", odds[i]);

for (int i = 0; i < evenIdx; ++i)
    printf("Even: %d\n", evens[i]);
```

---

As a final note, you don't really even need *any* arrays since, once you've written the number to the correct file (and you can do that as soon as you've read it), you can throw it away.

Doing it that way, handling errors, and allowing for any input size, would end up with a program like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    // Open all files, cleaning up on failure
    //   (fail fast strategy).

    FILE *fileIn, *fileEven, *fileOdd;

    if ((fileIn   = fopen("number.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open input file.");
        return -1;
    }

    if ((fileEven   = fopen("even.txt", "w")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create even file.");
        fclose(fileIn);
        return -1;
    }

    if ((fileOdd   = fopen("odd.txt", "w")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create odd file.");
        fclose(fileIn);
        fclose(fileEven);
        return -1;
    }

    // All open now, start processing input of any
    //   size, stop when no numbers left (end of
    //   file, or invalid number).

    while (fscanf(fileIn, "%d", &value) == 1) {
        // Allocate to odd or even file.

        if (value % 2 == 0) {
            fprintf(fileEven, "%d ", value);
        } else {
            fprintf(fileOdd, "%d ", value);
        }

        // Or could be "clever" with:
        //   fprintf((value % 2 == 0) ? fileEven : fileOdd, "%d ", value);

    }

    // Put newline at end of output files, just to be
    //   nice, then close all files and exit.

    fputc('\n', fileEven);
    fputc('\n', fileOdd);

    fclose(fileIn);
    fclose(fileEven);
    fclose(fileOdd);

    return 0;
}
```

And please (if this is classwork) use this code to educate yourself, rather than try and pass it off as your own. You would be foolish to assume your educators do not check for plagiarism.

Answer (score 0):

vals in these arrays.

```
index 0 1 2 3 4 ...
a     1 2 3 4 5 ...
e     # 2 # 4 # ...
o     1 # 3 # 5 ...
```

`#` are random numbers.

you need rethink the loop logic.

BTW, this would be easier to read

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    int a[25], i = 0, o[25], e[25];
    fp = fopen("number.txt", "r");

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &a[i]);
        if (a[i] < 2 && a[i] > -2) {
            if (a[i] == 0)
                e[i] = a[i];
            else
                o[i] = a[i];
        } else if (a[i] % 2 == 0)
            e[i] = a[i];
        else
            o[i] = a[i];
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen("even.txt", "w+");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        fprintf(fp, "%d ", e[i]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen("odd.txt", "w+");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        fprintf(fp, "%d ", o[i]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```